# Recursive relationship in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table which stores the customer , related customer  and count of related customers.
The related customer can have again further related customers it's like a recursive relationships.

I wanted to find out all the related customers ( till the last related customer ) for a customer.

### Table stats :-

Present volume is 2,00,000 records .

```
Create table
--------------
CREATE TABLE RELATED_TABLE 
( CUS_ID            VARCHAR2(09) ,
  REL_CUS_ID        VARCHAR2(09) ,
  COUNT_OF_REL_CUST NUMBER(12)) ;

Sample data:-
---------------  
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('402758970','898196448',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('402758970','855115206',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('402758970','850353774',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('898196448','691094946',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('898196448','404636299',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('898196448','402758970',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('855115206','870397045',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('855115206','855115206',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('855115206','402758970',3);


CUS_ID     REL_CUS_ID    COUNT_OF_REL_CUST   
402758970  898196448       3                                                          
402758970  855115206       3                                                          
402758970  850353774       3                                     
898196448  691094946       3                                     
898196448  404636299       3                                     
898196448  402758970       3                                            
855115206  870397045       3                                            
855115206  855115206       3                                            
855115206  402758970       3

OUTPUT:-
--------------------

402758970  898196448
402758970  855115206
402758970  850353774
402758970  691094946
402758970  404636299
402758970  870397045
402758970  855115206
```

Comment: you  can use self-referential integrity constraint. and self join to get the result.

Comment: I had used something like below

Comment: select * from (
   select connect_by_root(cus_id) cus_id, rel_cus_id
   from RELATED_TABLE
   start with rel_cus_id is not null
   connect by prior cus_id = rel_cus_id)
where cus_id <> rel_cus_id ; 
but this is givving me an error saying loop in user data

Comment: instead of adding that as a comment, you should [edit] your question, and add the details there.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the output using below SQL

```
SQL> SELECT  DISTINCT '402758970' CUS_ID,
  2                   REL_CUS_ID
  3    FROM  RELATED_TABLE
  4    START WITH CUS_ID = '402758970'
  5    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR REL_CUS_ID = CUS_ID
  6  /

CUS_ID    REL_CUS_ID
--------- ---------
402758970 898196448
402758970 691094946
402758970 870397045
402758970 402758970
402758970 404636299
402758970 850353774
402758970 855115206
```

Comment: You should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer so that your question is marked as resolved.